# how to get AccessToken to access web api secured with Azure AD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have a web api application (http://localhost:54540) secured with Azure AD like below,

[image]

Now I am trying to access web api from a regular MVC application using `OpenIdConnect`, here is the `startup` class for MVC,

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
    private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
    private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];
    private static string authority = aadInstance + tenantId;

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri
            });
    }
}
```

Now, I am trying to access web api into one of MVC controller like below,

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public string AccessToken
    {
        get
        {
            //var claim = Context.User?.FindFirst("access_token");
            //if (claim == null)
            //{
            //    throw new InvalidOperationException();
            //}

            //return claim.Value;
        }
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:54540/api/message");
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AccessToken);

            var response = await client.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();


            return View();
        }



    }
}
```

Question - what code is required to get `AccessToken`? Thanks!

Comment: You should check this sample app: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L92

Comment: The call to the API is done here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/Controllers/TodoListController.cs#L65

Comment: I checked out this sample, but is this is the only way to get it. the sample is also using Graph API, which I don't want

Comment: Since you have a back-end Web App which uses OIDC, that approach is the typical one. To use another API, just switch the resource URI to your API's App ID URI.

Comment: Is there way I can use https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

Comment: That's the v2 endpoint :) I think the Azure "easy auth" stuff does not support it yet. And with v2 you would need to use MSAL instead of ADAL.

Comment: When you use Azure Active Directory as the authentication provider, it's using Azure AD v1 endpoint,NOT v2 endpoint. The v2 endpoint is used for Microsoft Account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, you are using [App Service Authentication / Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview) (EasyAuth) for your WebAPI application hosted on Azure Web App without adding the related authentication middleware (e.g. [Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory/)) in your WebAPI application.

For accessing WebAPI from your MVC web application using OpenIdConnect, you could follow the approaches below:

**For AAD v1.0 app**, you could create your AAD app for the MVC application on Azure Portal and set the required permission for accessing the WebAPI AAD app. Then, you could follow the tutorial provided by juunas to add the `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` method to retrieve the token via ADAL and cache the retrieved token, then you could use `authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync` to acquire the access token in the subsequent requests without asking for user credential.

```
    private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context)
    {
        var code = context.Code;

        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
        string userObjectID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID));

        // If you create the redirectUri this way, it will contain a trailing slash.  
        // Make sure you've registered the same exact Uri in the Azure Portal (including the slash).
        Uri uri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path));

        AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, uri, credential, "<resource, you could specify it to the AAD app ClientId for your WebAPI application>");
    }
```

**Note:** For the `resource` parameter in `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync` , you could set it to the AAD app ClientId for your WebAPI application instead of `graphResourceId` in the github sample. And if there is no valid token in tokenCache when you invoking `authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync`, then you could encounter the following error:

[image]

**For AAD v2.0 app**, you need to register app at [App Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/). I have checked that EasyAuth could work well with v2.0 app, you could just configure the AAD authentication using the clientId,clientSecret of your v2.0 app on Azure Portal. For this approach, when working with OpenIdConnect, you need to MSAL to use `ConfidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync` to acquire the token and use `ConfidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenSilentAsync` in the subsequent request. Details you could follow [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample/blob/master/Graph-ASPNET-46-Snippets/Microsoft%20Graph%20ASPNET%20Snippets/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs) for OpenIdConnect related code sample and [SampleAuthProvider](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample/blob/master/Graph-ASPNET-46-Snippets/Microsoft%20Graph%20ASPNET%20Snippets/Helpers/SampleAuthProvider.cs) about `AcquireTokenSilentAsync`.

Moreover, if you are handling [Daemon or Server Application to Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api) without user interaction, you could just use the OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Grant flow and provide the clientId and clientSecret to acquire the access token via using MSAL for v2.0 app or ADAL for v1.0 app.

Comment: will there be any cross site forgery or any drawback for `EasyAuth`

Comment: AFAIK, Easy Auth is a native IIS module provided by Azure side. It helps you to easily integrate the authentication into your web application. Details you could follow [Architecture of Azure App Service Authentication / Authorization](http://cgillum.tech/2016/02/01/architecture-of-azure-app-service-authentication-authorization/). For CSRF, I assumed that you need to handle it  by yourself.

Comment: is there any code implementation to get access token to web api that has oauth2 authentication? I was hoping to use the HttpClient of ASP.NET Web API but I don't know how it can be implement